# How can I stop something happening again before it is finished?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I have this storyboard where I have a animation that lasts 3 seconds. It's triggered by a `Image` `Tap` event, but I don't want the user to trigger it again before it is finished. The storyboard has a `Completed` event.

Is there I way I can lock the storyboard `Begin` and unlock it at `Completed`?

Comment: Google "mutual exclusion".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could wrap your control into class, add bool IfRunning property to that class and check it each time when user taps again.

your code will look similar to this:

(raise on Tap event)

```
if(IfRunning==false) 
{
IfRunning=true;
BeginAnimation();
}
```

...
(raise in Completed event)

```
EndAnimation(); 
IfRunning=false;
```